# Execute a batch file in C#

Tags: c#

I have a batch file which basically downloads a file from a site or returns a error message saying files are not available. I want to execute this .bat file in C#(SSIS script component) and save the file name to a variable(if the file is downloaded) or assign the error message to the variable.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why not do the download in SSIS directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the System.Diagnostics.Process to run the Cmd.exe with the /C option.  Provide the name of the batch file and your basically there.  To ease wrapping the Process creation and capture of std input and output I recommend looking at the [ProcessRunner](http://code.google.com/p/csharptest-net/source/browse/trunk/src/Library/Processes/ProcessRunner.cs) class I put together some time ago.  If not at least read through this article on [How to use System.Diagnostics.Process correctly](http://csharptest.net/?p=321).

Additionally, you might look at the [ScriptRunner](http://code.google.com/p/csharptest-net/source/browse/trunk/src/Library/Processes/ScriptRunner.cs) class in the same library which creates a wrapper around running several different types of Windows OS script files.

Answer (score 10):

Execute the batch file using [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx). You can get the process output as text by reading StandardError and StandardOutput streams on the returned Process object. You will need to set the `RedirectStandardOutput` property to true.

Here is an example from MSDN:

```
 Process p = new Process();
 // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 p.StartInfo.FileName = "yourbatchfile.bat";
 p.Start();
 // Read the output stream first and then wait.
 string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
 p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: ProcessStartInfo startInfo;
            Process batchExecute;

            startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\test\test.bat");
            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\test";
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

            batchExecute = new Process();
            batchExecute.StartInfo = startInfo;
            batchExecute.Start();
           
            batchExecute.WaitForExit();   i am using the fallowing code but how to store the output to a variable??

Comment: @ramesh, I added an example. You need to read the output text as a string, then parse it. The process _might_ return you a meaningful errorcode, which you can check by looking at `p.ExitCode`.

Comment: +0 - This code example is flawed, but it does cover the basics.  Potential issues exist if the batch file prompts for input or writes to std err.  Calling StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() will hang in either case.